# Master Page Not Loading Properly

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, web-hosting

I have spent a couple days trying to figure out why my asp master page format and controls are being ignored when I try to access a page from my IIS 7.5 server.

I'm using the basic DevStudio ASP web project and everything works when I reference the pages through localhost. But when I try to access it through the server the asp:Menu control in the master page, and any other formatting, is being ignored.

I turned on logging and the only thing I see is a warning that I'm getting access denied to the style sheet. I've added the style sheet folder to the IIS list of virtual directories - still not working.

Any help in resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give some code about ? where are you try to load  ? Maybe you have place your css in a reserve and not allowed directory.

Comment: Is there any error message that you get? Whre do you host your ASP site? Own server or with hosting provder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApplicationPool of your hosted website may not have the permission to access the files. Check the applicationpool credentials. If the controls not loaded properly, check the DateTime of your IIS server machine.If the future date time is set, you will get this kind of misbehavior.

Comment: You are correct. The ASP 4.0 control process (w3wp.exe) is running as user - "ASP.NET V4.0 Intergrated" and that user did not have permission to access the style sheet to apply the styles to the asp:Menu control. Everything started working once I gave "Everyone" user Read & Read/Execute permissions to the css file. Thank you for getting me pointed in the right direction.